# Families of Fuchsian models

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, dg.differential-geometry, cv.complex-variables

A Fuchsian model for a Riemann surface $X$ is a discrete subgroup $G$ of $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ such that there is a biholomorphic map from $U/G$ to $X$.

For a fixed genus $g \geq 2$ one knows from Bers embedding theorem that there is a holomorphic family of all Fuchsian models parametrized by the Teichmueller space $T_g$. 
More precisely, the mapping $t \mapsto G_t$  depends holomorphically on $t$ where $G_t$ is the Fuchsian model for the Riemann surface represented by $t$.

My question is: does there exist another parametrization of Fuchsian models which is not the one I described above?

Or another question, that is very much connected to my question: is there another method than Bers' embedding to induce a complex structure on the Teichmueller space $T_g$?

Comment: $U=PSL_2(\mathbb R)$

Comment: I think $U$ is the upper half plane.

Comment: Right.  I wrote that a little too fast.

Comment: I'll delete my comment if you delete yours.

Comment: The original construction of a complex structure is due to Ahlfors: 
http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=124486

Answer (score 4):

I think the first question is not well-formed.  The Bers construction gives a holomorphically varying family of **quasi**-Fuchsian groups $G(t)$ (in $PSL_2(\mathbb{C})$) each of which has a simply-connected invariant domain $U(t)$ whose quotient is biholomorphic to the Riemann surface represented by $t$.  Both the groups and the domains are varying, as is necessary to obtain a holomorphic family.

For the second question, do you care about the actual complex structure (i.e. charts mapping open subsets of $\mathcal{T}_g$ into $\mathbb{C}^n$) or just the almost complex structure (multiplication by $i$ on a tangent space)?

The almost complex structure is easy to see in most models for Teichmuller space, because the tangent space at a point is typically represented by a complex vector space.  For example, $T_X \mathcal{T}_g$ can be seen as the linear dual of $Q(X)$, the vector space of holomorphic quadratic differentials on the Riemann surface $X$.  Multiplication of differentials by the constant function $i$ induces the almost complex structure.

Answer (score 2):

Since you seem to be working with curves that don't have punctures, your questions lie in the purview of Grothendieck's 1960-61 Seminaire Cartan paper: *[Techniques de construction en géométrie analytique. I. Description axiomatique de l'espace de Teichmüller et de ses variantes](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/SHC/SHC_1960-1961__13_1/SHC_1960-1961__13_1_A4_0/SHC_1960-1961__13_1_A4_0.pdf)* (I hope you like large pdfs in French).  This paper answers your second question in the positive, and even better, describes a moduli functor on complex analytic spaces that is represented by $T_g$.

I don't know enough about Fuchsian models to say anything about your first question.